# JUnit getAnnotation returns null

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I want to run a simple Rule that will try to rerun the test if it has a specific annotation.Specifically,it'll try to rerun the test as many times as the user wants,by reading the tries int from a cusotm annotationt.

Here is the cusotm annotation i created:
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Retry {
    int tries();
}
```

And here is the custom rule i created:

```
public class RetryRule implements TestRule {
    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement base, final Description description) {

        if( description.getAnnotation(Retry.class) == null ) {
            System.out.println("Hm...");
            return base;
        }

        int tries = description.getAnnotation(Retry.class).tries();

        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                while(true) {

                    int i = 1 ;
                    try {
                        i++;
                        base.evaluate();
                        return ;
                    } catch (AssertionError ex) {
                        if( i >= tries ) {
                            return ;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The problem is that whenever i run a test with the custom annotation and the custom rule,it always runs only once.I checked,and the getAnnotation(....) returns always null in any case — if cusotm annotation is specified or no.

Comment: `@Retention` has not been defined for your annotation. It'll be gone at runtime, leading to null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your annotation is not retained till runtime.
Use `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`